# how to save fragment data when fragment loads second time in android

Tags: android, fragment

I have one fragment , It have list of checkboxes, and some fields, What I want is when user selects checkboxes and go to next fragment, and when comes back , that checkboxes needs to keep its state, checked or unchecked.

Comment: You can use sharepreference for this task u need to just store array list in sharepreference and use that when you load fragment second time...you can even use local database for this task

Comment: Try adding the first fragment in BackStack while going to next fragment

Comment: @yatish, I added in back to stack but API is calling each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you invoke the `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_container, fragment, tag).commit()`, this can lead your fragment recreate, just use `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show/hide(fragment).commit()`, the all status can keep always. If you still want to invoke `replace` to switch fragment, you can save the all status as shared data in his parent Activity, then you can save or restore the status of one Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preference is a good idea. The data will be stored in the shared preference and will be available at all times.It is possible to overwrite the data too.

This will give you a basic idea about the same: [Shared Preference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Example Code:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
getActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefKey, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("checked", "yes"); //set a flag if checked
    editor.apply();

SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefKey, MODE_PRIVATE);
if (prefs.contains("checked")){
            String chStatus= prefs.getString("checked",null);
            if((chStatus!=null)) {
               checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
```